# Access source object in ForAllMembers method

Tags: c#, automapper

Trying to skip property mapping based on a specific field on viewModel. Is there any way to access source object in ForAllMembers -> Condition method

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AViewModel, AEntity>()
      .IgnoreMembers(ignoreMembers)
      .ForAllMembers(o => {
          o.Condition(ctx => {
                        //Need to access AViewModel instance here
                return "Id" == ctx.MemberName;
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the official way, but you can use the `Parent` property on `ResolutionContext`

```
Mapper.CreateMap<AViewModel, AEntity>()
      .IgnoreMembers(ignoreMembers)
      .ForAllMembers(o => {
          o.Condition(ctx => {
                AViewModel instance = (AViewModel)ctx.Parent.SourceValue;
                return "Id" == ctx.MemberName;
    });
   });
```

If you are in multiple levels deep in the mapping you can "traverse up" the  `Parent` relation until you find the type what you are looking for.

Comment: I think this specifically answers the question but dealing with the ambiguity of where you are in an object hierarchy would make me want to avoid doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to do this another way using a custom ValueResolver.

See:

[Conditional projection using AutoMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522569/conditional-projection-using-automapper)